# Does the approximation related to the generalized quadratic Gauss sums hold?

Tags: integration, summation, approximation, euler-maclaurin

I have a generalized quadratic Gauss sums, which is defiend as

$$S(a,b) = \sum_{n = 0}^Ne^{-j(an + bn^2)}$$

where $a\in(-\pi,\pi)$, $b\in(0,\pi)$ and $n$ is an integer. Now I am trying to approximate this summation by integeral via

$$S(a,b) \approx \int_{n=0}^N {e^{-j(an + bn^2)}dn}$$
when $N$ is a large number. My concern is, under what condition, such an approxiamtion holds?

Comment: Hint: [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula)